# SaveXML() неправильно выводит информацию

Tags: xml, php

```
<?php ## Загрузка XML-документа методом LoadXML()
$domdocument = new DOMDocument ('1.0');
$xmldocument = '
<html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Пример XML-документа</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Пример XML-документа</H1>
<IMG SRC="picture1.gif" ALT="картинка 1" />
<IMG SRC="picture2.gif" ALT="картинка 2" />
</BODY>
</html>';
// Построить дерево документов по XML документу
$domdocument->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$domdocument->loadXML($xmldocument); 
echo "Вывод документа с отступами: \n";
$domdocument->formatOutput = true;
echo $domdocument->saveXML(); // вывести документ с отступами
echo "<br>";
echo "Вывод документа одной строкой: \n";
$domdocument->formatOutput=false;
echo $domdocument->saveXML();

?>
```

Результат работы:

```
Вывод документа с отступами:
Пример XML-документа
картинка 1 картинка 2
Вывод документа одной строкой:
Пример XML-документа
картинка 1 картинка 2
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводило правильно?

Comment: @EduardRST, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А как по-Вашему правильно?
Может, стоит заголовок добавить `header("Content-Type: text/xml");`?

Comment: Нет, не получается. Добился результата с помощью htmlspecialchars() и <pre>